# Convert only parts of XML to JSON

Tags: php, json, xml

I have this XML (example):

```
<rows>
    <row id="123">
        <district>123</district>
        <email>test@gmail.com</email>
        <area>V</area>
    </row>
</rows>
```

I get that online XML from a URL. 
And I'm converting to JSON with the following PHP code: 
($url is the variable with the URL of my XML above.)

```
<?php

class XmlToJson {

    public function Parse ($url) {

        $file = file_get_contents($url);
        $file = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $file);
        $file = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $file));

        $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($file);
        $json = json_encode($simpleXml);
        return $json;
    }
}
?>
```

Which returns (example):

```
{
   "rows": {
      "row": [
         {
            "@attributes": {
               "id": "4310"
            },
            "district": "123",
            "email": "teste@gmail.com",
            "area": "V"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How do I generate the JSON without these tags "rows" and "row"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example XML string with a **single row** returns this json :

```
 {"row":{"@attributes":{"id":"123"},"district":"123","email":"test@gmail.com","area":"V"}}
```

I'm assuming to get the json your example there are additional tags surrounding the `<rows>` tag like

```
<xml>
 <rows>
<row id="123">
    <district>123</district>
    <email>test@gmail.com</email>
    <area>V</area>
</row>
</rows>
</xml>
```

Simple XML coverts your xml string to an object.  Just access the specific property of the generated object you want to convert json.

Try this:

```
 $json = json_encode($simpleXml->rows->row);
```